# Issue with repeat-x in CSS

Tags: css, background

Repeat-x property for CSS is not working as required.

I have a 50px image (to be used as background image).

I take a 200px div and set the 50px image as background with repeat-x css property.

The problem I am facing is 4 images (4 * 50px = 200px) are correctly drawn and a little portion of the image is also drawn at the end. As I think this extra portion should not be drawn. Please help.

css property:

```
{
 width:200px;
 height:27px;
 position:absolute;
 background:url(./img/common/bg_grid.jpg) repeat-x left top;
  background-size:50px 27px;
 }
```

[image]

[image]

from above link you may find correct background image

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please put this on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: may be parent div having padding...remove that

Comment: <div style="width:1350px;height:27px;background-color:#0000dd;position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px"></div>
  <div style="width:1350px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:150px;left:100px;background:url(./img/common/bg_grid.jpg) repeat-x left top;overflow:hidden;background-size:45px 27px;background-repeat: space;margin:0;padding:0"></div> Here is similar code.In this also we are facing the same problem however it is free from all kind of parent tags. 'm not able upload image coz of less reputation :(

Comment: somehow managed to create fiddle but not with correct image here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/shivthecoder/c9j2D/ the only change is it is not having border drawn at right

Comment: updated jsfiddle with correct image http://jsfiddle.net/shivthecoder/c9j2D/2/

Comment: its working fine right

Comment: 'm getting extra portion same as highlighted above with yellow circle on asked question here is fiddle with right property instead of left for clear understanding http://jsfiddle.net/shivthecoder/c9j2D/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain level of `margin` or `padding` that is inheriting its default value from the nested/parent elements. You need to reset them in order to get what you are looking for.

From your above code, **For Instance,**

```
{
 width:200px;
 height:27px;
 position:absolute;
 background:url(./img/common/bg_grid.jpg) repeat-x left top;
 background-size:50px 27px;
 padding:0; /* Reset values */
 margin:0; /* Reset values */
 }
```

**EDIT:**

As per the updated fiddle provided by the OP, below is the solution.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c9j2D/5/)**

**The CSS Code Change:**

```
<div style="width:900px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:150px;right:100px;background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ebiu.jpg) repeat-x left top;overflow:hidden;background-size:45px 28px;background-repeat: space;margin:0;padding:0"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you put the part of code which is having the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is the code <div style="width:1350px;height:27px;background-color:#0000dd;position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px"></div>
<div style="width:1350px;height:27px;position:absolute;top:150px;left:100px;background:url(./img/common/bg_grid.jpg) repeat-x left top;overflow:hidden;background-size:45px 27px;background-repeat: space;margin:0;"></div>
  but I don't know any open site where I can upload my image.and provide link for background

Comment: Go to www.jsfiddle.net and paste the HTML and CSS for your code. - @user3110561

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shivthecoder/c9j2D/ here is the link but image is not correct it has dark border on right

Comment: as you can check at the very right end it leaves some portion but it should by fully occupied http://jsfiddle.net/shivthecoder/c9j2D/3/    the width of div is 900 and every background image width is 45 px so I think there should no extra portion of the image should be visible at end same thing is highlighted on my question asked above

Comment: Its not 45px, its 46px and the `border-right` is the culprit which is repeating itself everytime and that is causing the gap. - @user3110561

Comment: even if we change 45px to 46px and width to 920px instead of 900px 'm getting the same problem.right border is in image itself only no extra css attribute is applied

Comment: Here is the solution. http://jsfiddle.net/c9j2D/5/ Hope this is what you want. - @user3110561

Comment: I have updated my answer for the above. You can have a look. - @user3110561

Comment: requesting you please check rear end it still is having extra portion left in same way as highlighted with yellow circle on asked question

Comment: I made css changes and it is gone now. Please re-check my latest fiddle that I have updated in my answer. - @user3110561

Comment: I have highlighted the issue on your fiddle here is the link http://i.stack.imgur.com/y30kK.png

Comment: That is not my fiddle. My fiddle is this http://jsfiddle.net/c9j2D/5/ - @user3110561

Comment: as width is factor of 45 so it should not have any extra portion left

Comment: The issue is of background size of 27, which needs to be changed to 28 and that resolves your issue. I have not changed anything else. - @user3110561

Comment: here is the link of image of rear end http://i.stack.imgur.com/p75ir.png it is still having extra portion left

Comment: Its not visible at my end - @user3110561

Comment: could you share the screenshot of rear end of your js fiddle which is not occupying any extra portion of it?

Comment: yes the screenshot you have provided is not having any extra portion but on my screen it is clearly visible

Comment: What browser are you looking at? I checked on chrome and Firefox and it is working perfectly fine. - @user3110561

Comment: IE-10 and chrome not checked with firefox yet

Comment: try it without background-repeat:space

Comment: It works perfectly fine there too. http://jsfiddle.net/c9j2D/11/ Here is the snapshot too http://i.imgur.com/MnzYhYv.png - @user3110561

Comment: Sorry to say but it is not working at my end in any of the above mentioned browser

Comment: Then you need to clear your browser cache/cookies and still it does not work, you need to instal it again. - @user3110561

Comment: But I have launched your fiddle for first time so I don't think it would be issue of cache and it is the problem with both the browser

Comment: Well I can't say more, as I cannot see what issue you are facing, but it is evident that there is an issue, as it is working fine on my machine as well as other machines near me. - @user3110561

Comment: do you see issue in my fiddle?

Comment: Yes. And when I correct it, I also see mine working. As you mentioned you are checking in chrome, it works perfectly fine for me there too. - @user3110561

Comment: what are the changes you have made ?

Comment: changed background-size value of 27 to 28. - @user3110561

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
.content
{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
    background:#ccc;
    height:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c9j2D/7/

Comment: Sorry to say but I think you are not getting the question correctly my problem is "the width of div is 900px and every background image width is 45px so I think there should no extra portion of the image should be visible at end" It should show 20 blocks(45 * 20 = 900) and no extra portion of the image at all at rear portion of it as highlighted with yellow circle on asked question

Comment: k k ur img having 46px width use 45px correctly it ll be corrent...for example i changed the image see the updated link..

Comment: Even if I change background width to 46px and divs width to 920px it is not occupying whole space (46 * 20 = 920)

Comment: see the updated link form my image...and see this http://jsfiddle.net/c9j2D/12/ for ur image

Comment: still I see the issue

Comment: please see the screenshot shared with Nathan Lee

Comment: if u hav site url give that

Comment: sry its perfectly working in my side...nothing to do